# Help to find synonym to 'ego-drive'

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I need to translate a word combination '*ego-driven insecurity'* into my language, but what is ego-driven? The Babylon dictionary gives a definition '*the need of one individual to persuade another to a particular point of view and feel satisfaction in having done so"*. How to say it simpler? I can't find an equivalent in my language, maybe there are any synonyms to help me?

Comment: Napolean complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very closely related concept to the ideas conveyed by "ego-driven"  is that of ***[egoism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/egoist):***

> - the habit of valuing everything only in reference to one's personal interest (opposed to altruism).

The Free Dictionary